# Twig to XLIFF translate in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig, multilingual, xliff

I haven't understood exactly how the xliff and twig files work together with Symfony2.

In my twig I wrote this

```
<article>{{ 'bye'|trans }}</article>
```

and the it xliff file "*Resurces/translations/messages.it.xliff*" (this is just a snippet)

```
<trans-unit id="2" datatype="plaintext">
    <source xml:lang="en">Bye</source>
    <target xml:lang="it">Ciao</target>
</trans-unit>
```

It works good and when the url language-segment is "it", it translates in it language (Ciao).

Instead, How I can make a similar thing without fall in error?

```
<trans-unit id="2" datatype="plaintext">
    <source xml:lang="en"><a href="link.html">Bye</a></source>
    <target xml:lang="it"><a href="link.html">Ciao</a></target>
</trans-unit>
```

Above there's just an example of what I would like to do. I sow a lot of stuff about this matter but I'm still confused.

The problem is when I should translate a string with HTML tags inside.

Comment: http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/xliff-profile-html/xliff-profile-html-1.2-cd02.html#Structure_MappingElements

Comment: Is this a question about how to offer different HTML based on the language? What do you want to translate? Should there be something like `bye.html` and `ciao.html`?

Comment: I would like to translate the entire string "<a href="link.html">Bye</a>" in "<a href="link.html">Ciao</a>".
This have sense in such case like this: "<a href="link.html">Hi</a>, how are <b>you</b>?"

Comment: maybe it's better an example with a translate like below:

"click <a href="link">here</a> for preview"
in
"clicca <a href="">qui</a> per l'anteprima"

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found the solution.

In my *twig* file:

```
{{ 'click <a href="#link">here</a> for more info'|trans|raw }}
```

in my *xliff* file ( trans-unit tag snippet):

```
<trans-unit id="3" datatype="html">
 <source xml:lang="en"><![CDATA[click <a href="#link">here</a> for more info]]></source>
 <target xml:lang="fr"><![CDATA[clicca <a href="#link">qui</a> per maggiori info]]></target> 
</trans-unit>
```

with *en* set up as main language.